# WildFly 10, JGroups and EC2

Tags: wildfly

I'm trying to run WildFly 10 with the HA profile in EC2, but am getting the following errors:

```
05:03:28,308 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/protocol=FD_SOCK' are not available:
[Server:server-one]     org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.jgroups-tcp-fd; There are no known registration points which can provide this capability.
[Server:server-one] 05:03:28,310 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0362: Capabilities required by resource '/subsystem=jgroups/stack=tcp/transport=TCP' are not available:
[Server:server-one]     org.wildfly.network.socket-binding.jgroups-tcp; There are no known registration points which can provide this capability.
```

My JGroups config looks like this

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jgroups:4.0">
                <channels default="ee">
                    <channel name="ee" stack="tcp"/>
                </channels>
                <stacks>
            <stack name="tcp">
                <transport type="TCP" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp"/>
                <protocol type="S3_PING">
                    <property name="access_key">accesskey</property>
                    <property name="secret_access_key">secretkey</property>
                    <property name="location">bucketname</property>
                </protocol>
                <protocol type="MERGE3"/>
                <protocol type="FD_SOCK" socket-binding="jgroups-tcp-fd"/>
                <protocol type="FD"/>
                <protocol type="VERIFY_SUSPECT"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.NAKACK2">
                    <property name="use_mcast_xmit">false</property>
                    <property name="use_mcast_xmit_req">false</property>
                </protocol>
                <protocol type="UNICAST3"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.STABLE"/>
                <protocol type="pbcast.GMS"/>
                <protocol type="MFC"/>
                <protocol type="FRAG2"/>
                <protocol type="RSVP"/>
            </stack>
        </stacks>
</subsystem>
```

Does anyone know what `There are no known registration points which can provide this capability` means?

Comment: did you just change the tcp stack? Should you add a new s3ping stack instead of the tcp one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out that I had mixed up my socket bindings. I was using the ha profile with full-ha-sockets socket binding, like this:

```
<server-groups>
        <server-group name="main-server-group" profile="ha">
            <jvm name="default">
                <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
            </jvm>
            <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/> <!-- THIS IS BROKEN -->
            <deployments>
                <deployment name="activemq-rar" runtime-name="activemq-rar"/>
                <deployment name="hawtio.war" runtime-name="hawtio.war"/>
            </deployments>
        </server-group>
        <server-group name="other-server-group" profile="full-ha">
            <jvm name="default">
                <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
            </jvm>
            <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/>
        </server-group>
    </server-groups>
```

Once I had fixed the socket-bindings, the errors went away:

```
<server-groups>
        <server-group name="main-server-group" profile="ha">
            <jvm name="default">
                <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
            </jvm>
            <socket-binding-group ref="ha-sockets"/> <!-- THIS IS FIXED -->
            <deployments>
                <deployment name="activemq-rar" runtime-name="activemq-rar"/>
                <deployment name="hawtio.war" runtime-name="hawtio.war"/>
            </deployments>
        </server-group>
        <server-group name="other-server-group" profile="full-ha">
            <jvm name="default">
                <heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>
            </jvm>
            <socket-binding-group ref="full-ha-sockets"/>
        </server-group>
    </server-groups>
```

Comment: This is for `domain.xml` file the same error I am getting with `standalone-ha.xml` what should be the alternatives of `server-groups` in `standalone-full-ha.xml` because as per my scenario I have to use `standalone-ha.xml` for clustering.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar problem too. But, instead of the problem be in the `<server-group />`, my problem was in my host.

I create an initial host to use the profile `full-ha` and `full-ha-sockets` in a server-group already existent. After that, I create a new server-group using the profile `ha` and `ha-sockets` and move this host to this new server-group.

The problem? My host was using the profile `ha` but with `full-ha-sockets` instead of `ha-sockets`. I made a setup to use EJB Remote using only `ha-sockets` and have this same error when I was trying to call the remote method in the EJB for the *remote outbound connection*:

```
There are no known registration points which can provide this capability
```

I was thinking that my host was using the `ha-sockets`. So, I put the host to use `ha-sockets` and the error was gone. I lost a lot of time to discover this mistake.